# Why is my Azure DevOps YAML build triggered on PR when I only configured CI branches

Tags: azure-devops

In my project I want to configure a **CI** and a **PR** build. I chose these to be separate builds, because the status badge gets dirtied if the same build is used for both CI and PR.

In my CI build I configured

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - 'master'
```

However, when I create a PR, it gets triggered. Even in the Azure DevOps UI I can see the PR trigger as being "enabled" (see below). Note that I do not override any trigger.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `pr: none` in the yaml file to stop **PR** triggers. By default it is triggered for all branches. For **CI** also it is same.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#pr-triggers